# android sdk custom keyboard not moving app

Tags: android, sdk, keyboard, move

I think this issue was posted before. I'm having a custom keyboard and I need to make the app move above it like the softKeyboard with adjust does. Is it possible to do this? Can WindowManager help in any way?
if it's not possible, is it possible to assign a custom soft keyboard to an editbox in the app without prompting the user the dialog for choosing the custom soft keyboard?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Can WindowManager help in any way?

WindowManager won't help here, but if you add your entire Keyboard layout to the end of your Activity's layout tree, it should push all other elements up. Using the WindowManager will allow you to "float" the keyboard above the rest of your View.

> without prompting the user the dialog for choosing the custom soft keyboard?

This is not allowed for security reasons. You could override `onTouch()` for that EditText and show your own custom keyboard, but that's about all you can do.